# how to loop for division funciton in r

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a list such that: (my function is more complex than this example with many vectors that are vary from data to another). The idea of my function is to divide each element of the first vector over the sum of all elements of all vectors. That is, I am looking for something like this:

`mylist[[1]]+mylist[[2]]+....+mylist[[100]]`

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(3,4,5,6)
z <- list(x,y)
```

Then I would like to divide each element of the first element of the list by the sum of the first element of the first and second element of the list, such that:

```
z[[1]] / (z[[1]] + z[[2]])
```

The output is:

```
[1] 0.2500000 0.3333333 0.3750000 0.4000000
```

I would like to make it doing the division automatically. That because the number of my vectors inside the list are vary. So, I used `lapply`

```
f <- lapply(z, function(x) (x/sum(x)))
```

The output is:

```
  > f
    [[1]]
    [1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4

    [[2]]
    [1] 0.1666667 0.2222222 0.2777778 0.3333333
```

The output is wrong. I know that because my `f` function does not do the job in correct way. So, how can I fix it? any help please?

I also tried `for` loop such that:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  z[[i]] / (sum(z[[i]]))
}
```

This also does not solved my problem. So in the sum I would like to sum all the element of the list.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `lapply` here when the non-lapply version works just fine?

Comment: Your `lapply` is doing `z[[i]] / sum(z[[i]])` for i in {1, 2}. For i=1, you have 1:4 / 10, so it returns what you told it to. `lapply` is meant to work on each element of its first argument independently.

Comment: @MrFlick I have many lists and I think `lapply` is much more faster.

Comment: You have many lists with two vectors? I'm not sure I understand. And simple math operations like `+` and `/` will surely be faster than `lapply`. Most for loops can be written to be faster than `lapply`. It's not used for speed, it's used for convenience.

Comment: @MrFlick suppose I have 7 element stored in a list where each vector contains `1500` numbers. so how can I do it with `for` loop.

Comment: Do you have a list of lists? with only 1500 elements you won't notice much of a difference in speed. I guess it would be nice if your example were just a bit closer to what you are really doing. I don't see the complexity here.

Comment: sorry I update my comment. I have a list with many vectors. so for each vector I need to do the division of each one over the sum of all of them.

Comment: @MrFlick my example is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: `for (i in 1:2){
  z[[i]] / (sum(z[[i]]))
}`  this does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hard time work with this problem. I found this is the easiest way to do so.

```
t <- list()
for (i in 1:2){

 t[[i]] <- z[[i]] / Reduce("+", z)
}
```

And with `lapply` becomes:

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) z[[i]] / Reduce("+", z))
```